# How to capture the value of options in a select dropdown for comparison?

Tags: select, cypress

I have a dropdown on my dashboard that will redirect the user to a new page based on the value of the option they chose. All the IDs in the dropdown are also the route in the URL, so I figured I could just select whatever option in the list and just assert that the URL route contains that value.

I'm just having trouble figuring out how to get the value of the selected option saved to a variable in the test itself.

The test I have so far. Right now I have a variable that I would like to store the value (`selectedIssueID`), but getting a `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')` error.

I'm a bit lost here, so if anyone has any ideas, I would really appreciate it!

```js
 it.only('Issue Analysis dropdown functionality check', () => {
   // Assert there are options in the dropdown
    cy.get('[data-cy=issue-analysis-select-issue-dropdown]').should(
      'have.length.gt',
      0
    )
   // grab the last option and store the value 
    let selectedIssueID = ''
    cy.get('[data-cy=issue-analysis-select-issue-dropdown] option')
      .last()
      .then(($lastOption) => {
        cy.get('[data-cy=issue-analysis-select-issue-dropdown]')
          .select($lastOption.text())
          .then((selectedIssueID = $lastOption.text()))
          .log(selectedIssueID)
      })
    // Assert it routes properly
    cy.url().should('include', `/analysis/${selectedIssueID}`)
  })
```

**HTML** (The `CInput` component itself is a all-encompassing input just with styles and some vuejs helpers)

```html
<select
  data-cy="issue-analysis-select-issue-dropdown"
  id="0.2137294948228743"
  class="
    appearance-none
    border-0
    text-secondary-text text-sm
    bg-transparent
    min-w-min
    py-2
    pl-1
    leading-tight
    focus:outline-none
  "
  style="box-shadow: none"
>
  <option disabled="" value="" style="display: none;">Select an Issue You Want to Analyze</option>
  <option class="text-secondary-text" value="1">1</option>
  <option class="text-secondary-text" value="2">2</option>
  <option class="text-secondary-text" value="3">3</option>
  <option class="text-secondary-text" value="4">4</option>
  <option class="text-secondary-text" value="5">5</option>
  <option class="text-secondary-text" value="6">6</option>
  <option class="text-secondary-text" value="7">7</option>
  <option class="text-secondary-text" value="8">8</option>
  <option class="text-secondary-text" value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$lastOption.val()`? It is possible that the element doesn't have a traditional text value that JQuery can find, but instead is just displaying the value (reference by `.val()`

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Unfortunately if I do `.val()` I get a different error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')`. So still a typeError, but I've never seen this `reading 'apply' ` error before. This error is happening at the `.then()` point of the test fwiw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a bit of a syntax error in `.then((selectedIssueID = $lastOption.text()))`.

But I would also perform saving the text first and then select the option, since that will cause a URL change and the page changes (you might lose the elements previously queried because of the page change)

**Update** adding an alias to allow `selectedIssueID` to be used in `.select()` command.
Ref: [backflips](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Aliases)

```js
// grab the last option and store the value 
cy.get('[data-cy=issue-analysis-select-issue-dropdown] option').last()
  .then(($lastOption) => selectedIssueID = $lastOption.text())
  .as('selectedIssueID')

cy.get('@selectedIssueID').then(selectedIssueID => {
  cy.get('[data-cy=issue-analysis-select-issue-dropdown]')
    .select(selectedIssueID)
})

// Assert it routes properly
cy.url().should('include', `/analysis/${selectedIssueID}`)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment and apologies on the late reply! Unfortunately this doesn't seem to fix the issue and I get this error: 

`cy.select() can only be called on a <select>. Your subject is a: <option disabled="" value="" style="display: none;">Select ...</option>`

Any idea why that is? The only disabled option there is in my select dropdown is the first option, so not positive why this error is occuring:/

Comment: It's a different problem. You just couldn't see this one because of the previous one.

Comment: You did not post any HTML , so we have to assume that you are correct in using `.select()`.  What exactly does the HTML look like?

Comment: Sorry about that!
 I've added the component to the code, but since it is a vuejs project, I didn't want to confuse anyone. This `CInput` component works the same way a normal input does, just combined. So the options here, `issue_id_list` is just an array of ids (strings or numbers)

Comment: Ok, that looks like the Vue source code but Cypress works with the running (compiled) HTML in the browser, so that's what you need to look at when debugging the test.

Comment: Whoops, updated. I honestly didn't really think to check that error, but knew that the first element is likely what the error was referencing because that is always my placeholder option. Didn't think that would matter for the purposes of this test if I'm grabbing the last item.

Comment: Ok, it's clear now - the error message is pointing to the problem. The `.select()` command should be applied to the `select` not the `option`, so just need to remove `option` from the `cy.get().select()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244240/discussion-between-lovelyandy-and-fody).

Answer (score 1):

You can use get the last option text and save it as an alias, then later get the alias and use it as an assertion on the url.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=issue-analysis-select-issue-dropdown] option')
  .last()
  .invoke('text')
  .as('lastOptionText')

cy.get('@lastOptionText')
  .then(lot => {
    cy.get('[data-cy=issue-analysis-select-issue-dropdown] option')
      .select(lot)
    cy.url().should('include', `/analysis/${lot}`)
  })
```

If you want to continue with your approach, you'd have to do some shifting around of your code to do the same.

```js
let selectedIssueID

beforeEach(() => {
  // grab the last option and store the value 
  cy.get('[data-cy=issue-analysis-select-issue-dropdown] option')
    .last()
    .then(($lastOption) => {
      selectedIssueID = $lastOption.text()
    })
})

it.only('Issue Analysis dropdown functionality check', () => {
  // Assert there are options in the dropdown
  cy.get('[data-cy=issue-analysis-select-issue-dropdown]').should(
    'have.length.gt',
    0
  )
  cy.get('[data-cy=issue-analysis-select-issue-dropdown]')
    .select(selectedIssueID)

  // Assert it routes properly
  cy.url().should('include', `/analysis/${selectedIssueID}`)
})
```

Comment: How does an alias help? Seems like `invoke('text')` repairs the problem, the alias is just extra noise.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! If I try the first block of code you wrote I get an error that reads `cy.select() can only be called on a <select>. Your subject is a: <option disabled="" value="" style="display: none;">Select ...</option>`

It's not until I use the beforeEach version and declare the variable outside of the tests that this version works. It does work though! So thank you for the help here!

Any idea why I get that error though?

Comment: Even if I remove the `option` from the `.get()` I get another error saying `cy.select() failed because this <option> you are trying to select is currently disabled` Which doesn't make much sense because it's the first option that would be disabled

Comment: Also, this works only with the forEach method, so unfortunately, it will make my other tests fail. Not sure if I need a conditional in there, but I've heard conditional testing like this isn't a good way to go

Comment: @user16695029 I assume there is more to the test than what was pasted. Just used it just in case, if it was just was shared then it wouldn't be needed.